# Back-end technology choice to handle multiple simultaneous operations

Tags: database, backend, simultaneous

I'm working on a project that is pretty demanding server-side and I don't know what technology I should use for the database, the server and the hardware.

Here are the criteria :

- the server will receive, once a day and almost **simultaneously**, number_of_users times answers to a question. Imagine a service where a question is asked to every user at the exact same time and they only have a window of 30 sec to answer.
- it will have to treat them all and **sort** them from best to worst. Imagine that we can easily calculate a distance from the correct answer that will be the sorting criteria. The goal is to publish the ranking within 20-30 seconds.
- the number of users could be 1000, 10000 or even more !

First, does it sound doable or really really hard to implement ? By really really hard, I mean that a bunch of experienced engineers are required.

If it's doable, what is the most appropriate solutions I should consider to implement such a service ? NoSQL or SQL ? What server should I use ?

Thanks a bunch for your help and let me know if you need more details !

Comment: Is more than one question at a time possible (i.e., could you have concurrent "contests" going on)?

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the advice !
@Kelly It would only be one question at a time.